# adding element names to nested object

Tags: javascript

I have following variable like below

> var test = [{…}, {…}, {…}]

I am trying to name to each element such that I can access elements by test.grade, test.name, and test.area. I can think of most primitive way to add names to each index, but what is the most elegant way to do this?

```
 var columns = //
    var a= {};
    var b= {};
    var c= {};

    for(var i =0; i< columns.length; i++){
      a[columns[i]] = this.geta[i];
      b[columns[i]] = this.getb[i];
      c[columns[i]] = this.getc[i];

    }

    var test = [];
    var Name0 = "name";
    var Name1 = "grade";
    var Name2 = "area";

    test.push(a,b,c);

//test = [{name: Mike, grade: 10}}, {name: Sarah, grade:25}},{name:chris, grade:0}}]
```

**This is how I want to format**

> [{A: {name: Mike, grade: 10}}, {B:{name: Sarah, grade:25}}, {C: {name:chris, grade:0}}]

Then I want to access elements, for example, res.A.name or res.B.grade...

Comment: Where are you getting LNorth, LSouth, and LWest from?

Comment: sorry! wrong names.. updated!

Comment: what about `test.push( { grade: 10, person: "Cho", area: "devtools" } )` ?

Comment: @TomášPospíšek hm? I already formatted as you mentioned in for loop. I need to add name to that element, so using your example I want to return something like, test.Info = {grade :10, person: "cho", area: "devtools"} after assigning test[0] to info somehow

Comment: Not entirely clear what objective is. Show some sample data and expected results. It would also help to explain how you need to use all this

Comment: @charlietfl Pleases refer to updated post

Comment: And the sample input for that? How are those 3 different names separated into those columns?

Comment: sorry, I should've clearly posted question. Pleases refer to updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access something by dot notation then it should be as object so

```
test.push({
   grade:"grade",
   person:"person",
   area:"area"
});
```

Then you can access elements of test array and properties of element like this

```
test[0].person;
test[0].grade;
test[0].area;
```

**EDIT** :
as object

```
test={};
test['Name0']={person:"person1",grade:1,area:"..."};
test['Name1']={person:"person2",grade:1,area:"..."};
test['Name2']={person:"person3",grade:1,area:"..."};
```

and access as

```
test.Name0.person
```

or whatever name you want to use it is string so use for/foreach

Comment: yes.. but I want to add name as an object instead of accessing by index. I do not want to hardcode anything. For example, test.info.person